# Angular material 2 MatAutocompleteTrigger

Tags: angular, angular-material2

My project using 3 autocomplete components in the same form, I am using following code to make text field blank when a user leaves without select any option,

```
@ViewChild(MatAutocompleteTrigger) bedTrigger:MatAutocompleteTrigger;
bedTrigger.panelClosingActions
        .subscribe(e => {
          console.log("ward");
          if (!(e && e.source)) {
            this.orgInfoForm.get('fieldName').setValue(null);
            this.wardTrigger.closePanel();
          }
});
```

bedTrigger alway reference to first autocomplete component , can't referecne to other two autocomplete component . I think  each autocompete get one MatAutocompleteTrigger , actuall only one  MatAutocompleteTrigger  for the form and this one reference first autocomplete component, I try

```
@ViewChild(MatAutocompleteTrigger) triggers:QueryList<MatAutocompleteTrigger>;
```

to reference all trigger but I get only one MatAutocompleteTrigger.Please guide me how to get MatAutocompleteTrigger reference to other two autocomplete component in angualr material 2 version 5.0.2.

Comment: I think the ViewChild will always just grab the first thing in the DOM that matches, so I don't think you can achieve what you are doing with just ViewChild. Have you tried using 3 separate template reference variables instead?

Answer (score 5):

This is a good one. OK, first of all, you should use @ViewChildren instead of @ViewChild, and a QueryList

```
@ViewChildren(MatAutocompleteTrigger) triggerCollection: QueryList<MatAutocompleteTrigger>;
```

Then, to access the trigger of each element, you should iterate:

```
for (var trigger of this.triggerCollection.toArray()) {
  trigger.panelClosingActions
  .subscribe(e => {
    if (!(e && e.source)) {
      // do whatever you need
    }
  });
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I know this is an old one, but how do you know which autoComplete element to target? I have two elements like the OP and I need to clean one once this is triggered, but I can't get a reference to which element should be cleared, trigger is only thrown on the afterViewInit